# Convert Numpy ndarray of dtype (uint8) to OpenCV readable image

Tags: python, windows, numpy, opencv, direct3d

Long story short - I'm learning how to do simple screen capture with this [D3DShot](https://github.com/SerpentAI/D3DShot) *(Python implementation of the Windows Desktop Duplication API)* library and pass the captured data straight to **OpenCV**.

Captured data is `np.ndarray` of `dtype` `uint8` with values in range `(0, 255)`. I've tried multiple suggestions here on Stack Overflow and other websites, but couldn't wrap my finger around this and constantly run into errors.

Here is my current code:

```
import d3dshot
import cv2

# D3D init
d = d3dshot.create(capture_output="numpy", frame_buffer_size=60)

# Choose display
for i, display in enumerate(d.displays):
    current_display = display
    print('[' + str(i+1) + '] ' + display.name + '\n')

# Set display
current_display.i = int(input("Select display by nr.: ")) - 1
d.display = d.displays[current_display.i]
print('\nYou\'ve selected [' + str(current_display.i) + '] ' + current_display.name)

# Start capturing
d.capture(target_fps=10,)

# Send frame to opencv
while True:
    #Displayed the image
    img = d.get_latest_frame()

    #Dump it like it's hot
    print(img.shape, img.dtype)
    """
    Here we will convert from np.ndarray of dtype uint8 to opencv supported img
    """
    # Pass img to Open CV
    cv2.imshow("Test Window", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The dump returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\capture.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(img.shape, img.dtype)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

My question of course is **how to convert from `np.ndarray` of `dtype` `uint8` to OpenCV supported image?**

Comment: Proper Numpy arrays are compatible with OpenCV.  What in your code fails and do you get an error message.  Add `print(img.shape, img.dtype)` after you extract img to see what you have. Usual issue is the frame grab is failing and you do not have any image.

Comment: It returns `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\capture.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(img.shape, img.dtype)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Comment: I believe that means your frame grab is empty. Sorry, I do not know D3DShot. Check that it is working and that you are accessing it properly and your code is proper.

Comment: I just found out that I have to make like `100`ms delay after init. That was the issue. Thank you for help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason was very simple.. D3DShot capture needed some delay (I set it to `100`ms) to initialize and the array finally wasn't empty and passed succesfully to OpenCV.
Here is the updated code:

```
import d3dshot
import cv2
import time

# D3D init
d = d3dshot.create(capture_output="numpy", frame_buffer_size=60)

# Choose display
for i, display in enumerate(d.displays):
    current_display = display
    print('[' + str(i+1) + '] ' + display.name + '\n')

# Set display
current_display.i = int(input("Select display by nr.: ")) - 1
d.display = d.displays[current_display.i]
print('\nYou\'ve selected [' + str(current_display.i) + '] ' + current_display.name)

# Start capturing
d.capture(target_fps=60)
time.sleep(0.1)

# Send frame to opencv
while True:
    #Displayed the image
    img = d.get_latest_frame()

    #Dump it like it's hot
    print(img.shape, img.dtype)

    # Send to Open CV
    cv2.imshow("Test Window", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```